# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.populateAction is not a function, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React! I keep getting this error message. I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrect. please help.

> "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.populateAction is not a function"

```
 componentWillMount () {
    this.props.populateAction()
  }
  cities(){
    var {populateFormsData} = this.props.globalState

    return populateFormsData.map((item) => {
      return <option value={item}>{item}</option>
    })
  }
  homeTypes(){

  }
  bedRooms(){

  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <section id="content-area">
          <Filter change={this.change} globalState={this.state} 
 populateAction={this.populateForms} />
          <Listings listingsData={this.state.filteredData} />
        </section>

      </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `populateAction()` function?

Comment: it is within render  under filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing basic concepts of React.

`<Component props={}` />` will populate props **DOWN** the render tree, your parent component is referencing values which you are sending to the

`<Filter />` component, inside `<Filter />` component you would be able to call `this.props.populateAction()` but not from the parent. In the parent component (that one which you've posted) `this.props.populateAction` is undefined

Assuming you want to achieve this.

**wrapper.js**

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  populateAction (where) { console.log(`Action called from ${where}`); }

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent populateAction={this.populateAction} />
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.populateAction('Child component')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <section id="content-area">
          <Filter change={this.change} globalState={this.state} 
 populateAction={this.props.populateAction} />
          <Listings listingsData={this.state.filteredData} />
        </section>

      </div>)
  }
}
```

**filter.js**

```
class Field extends React.Component {

  render() {
    this.props.populateAction('Filter component')
  }
}
```

Comment: you are totally right rookie mistake, i  had placed some of this information in the wrong js file worked out perfect thanks for the affirmation and help!